# Stuck in BIOS after restarting laptop?

Tags: linux, windows-8, boot, bios, linux-mint

Good day! I restarted my laptop today after it hung up on me. When it booted, it greeted me with the BIOS screen. Of course I tried to reboot again and the same thing happened. I looked at the boot tab, but the list of boot options are blank.

I am using asus ROG G751JT. It is dual booted with windows 10(upgraded from windows 8) and linux mint 17.

I would like to reformat this but everytime I insert a windows 8 usb installer, it slows down (like it takes 20 mins. before moving to the next screen in the install wizard). The farthest I have gone is this [screen](http://tr1.cbsistatic.com/hub/i/2012/11/08/2ff765ff-c3a4-11e2-bc00-02911874f8c8/Fig_G_11-9.png) but the mouse's loading animation just shows up, the entire window is disabled, and it's stuck like for hours!!! The partitions show up though, but I cant click on them due to the window being disabled.

I have also tried using a linux mint installer and I keep getting `input/output error during read on /dev/sda` when trying to install through the wizard. How do I resolve this issue? I hope this is isn't hardware related. This problem is really getting on my nerves. Please help.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It does seem like a hardware issue and would need to be troubleshooted as such.  You might want to try a different hard drive to begin your investigation and see if the drive is your only problem.

Comment: This is likely caused by a defective hard drive, or possibly (although less likely) a faulty disk controller or motherboard. I would try a different hard drive first and attempt the installation again, or boot to a Linux USB and check the hard drive for access and usability.